# C помощью одного folderbrowserdialog получить два пути к папке?

Tags: c#

Собственно, необходимо получить при одном  вызове folderbrowserdialog два  пути к папке.

Comment: к одной и той же?

Comment: к разным папкам

Comment: @Daria: WinForms или WPF?

Answer (score 1):

Это нельзя сделать средствами «из коробки». Но вы можете установить через nuget [Windows API CodePack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Shell), в котором есть нужный диалог.

После установки пакета вы можете написать:

```
var dlg = new CommonOpenFileDialog() { IsFolderPicker = true, Multiselect = true };
var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result != CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
    return;

var folders = dlg.FileNames; // тут список имён выбранных папок
```

Это даст пользователю возможность выбрать *несколько* папок. Ограничить их количество именно *двумя*, к сожалению, невозможно.

---

Кстати, в Visual Studio 2017 вы можете просто написать этот код, нажать <kbd>Ctrl + .</kbd> на `CommonOpenFileDialog`, и среда сама предложит вам установить нужный nuget-пакет.